模倣学習Behavior Cloningで平均損失が最小平均損失を更新すればポリシーを保存できるようにしたい
質問
現在、ビヘイビアークローンを用いてモデルを訓練しています。lossを取得し、100回（仮）のイテレーションでのlossの移動平均が最小値に達した際にポリシーを保存したいと考えています。しかし、訓練中にどのようにlossを取得するかがわかりません。
どなたかご存じでしたらご教授願いませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。
以下に、私の現在のセットアップの概要を示します。
環境
Python: 3.8
stable-baselines3 2.3.2
gymnasium: 0.29.1
imitation: 1.0.0 
コード
from imitation.util.logger import configure, HierarchicalLogger
from imitation.util.util import save_policy
from imitation.algorithms import bc
# ログの取り出し用
from imitation.algorithms.bc import BehaviorCloningLossCalculator, BCTrainingMetrics


# Initialize rng
rng = np.random.default_rng()

bc_trainer = bc.BC(
    observation_space=venv.observation_space,
    action_space=venv.action_space,
    # policy=expert.policy,
    demonstrations=flattened_transitions,
    rng=rng,
    l2_weight=0.01,
    device='auto'  # GPUを使用


# ロガーの設定

logger: HierarchicalLogger = configure(log_BC_dir, format_strs=('stdout', 'log', 'csv'))

# 最小の平均 loss を追跡
best_avg_loss = float('inf')
model_save_path = "path/to/save/model"  # モデルの保存先ディレクトリ
losses = []  # 各エポックの loss を保存するリスト

# トレーニングループ
total_epochs = 100  # 例として100エポック
epoch_group_size = 20  # 20エポックごとに平均 loss を計算

for epoch in range(total_epochs):
    # トレーニングを実行し、トレーニングメトリクスを取得
    metrics: bc.BCTrainingMetrics = bc_trainer.train(n_epochs=1)

    # loss を取得し、ログに記録
    last_loss = metrics.loss.item()  # Tensor を数値に変換
    losses.append(last_loss)
    logger.record("loss", last_loss)

     # 20エポックごとに平均 loss を計算
    if (epoch + 1) % epoch_group_size == 0:
        avg_loss = np.mean(losses[-epoch_group_size:])  # 直近20エポックの平均 loss を計算
        print(f"エポック {epoch + 1}: 直近{epoch_group_size}エポックの平均Loss: {avg_loss:.4f}")

        # 平均 loss が最小の場合、モデルを保存
        if avg_loss < best_avg_loss:
            best_avg_loss = avg_loss
            # bc_trainer.policy.save(os.path.join(policy_dir, f"best_bc_policy_{mean_reward:.3f}"))
            policy_path = os.path.join(policy_dir, f"best_bc_policy_epoch{epoch + 1}_avg_loss{best_avg_loss:.4f}")
            # ポリシーを保存
            save_policy(bc_trainer.policy, policy_path)

            print(f"新しいベストの平均報酬: {best_avg_loss}。モデルを保存しました。")

        else:
            print(f"平均Lossは改善されませんでした（現在: {avg_loss:.4f}, 最良: {best_avg_loss:.4f}）")

    # ログをダンプ（ファイルに保存）
    logger.dump(epoch)

エラーログ
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-e5be3a6a7185> in <cell line: 23>()
     26 
     27     # loss を取得し、ログに記録
---> 28     last_loss = metrics.loss.item()  # Tensor を数値に変換
     29     losses.append(last_loss)
     30     logger.record("loss", last_loss)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loss'

